# Xamarin Forms Android display pictures throws Exception

Tags: android, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms, resolution

Showing multiple pictures from a gallery within a page throws an exception. Displaying one photo with a resolution (e.g 3264x2488) on one page works. But when it comes to display more than one with a high resolution it crashes on Android. The higher the resolution the less can be displayed on a page.

https://github.com/Crunch91/RezepteTagebuch/blob/master/RezepteTagebuch/RezepteTagebuch/Views/RecipeView.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="RezepteTagebuch.Views.RecipeView">
    <...>
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Image Source="{Binding FoodPicture}"/>
      <Image Source="{Binding DescriptionPicture}"/>
    </StackLayout>
    </...>
```

I can see the same behaviour in my ListView. One photo in the ListView works well. Once I add another photo it crashes again.

https://github.com/Crunch91/RezepteTagebuch/blob/master/RezepteTagebuch/RezepteTagebuch/Views/AllRecipeView.xaml

```
<StackLayout>   
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Recipes}" x:Name="recipeList">    
    <...>
    <ViewCell>
      <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image WidthRequest="44" HeightRequest="44" Source="{Binding FoodPicturePath}" />              
      </StackLayout>
    </ViewCell>
    </...>
  </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

This is my repo where you can find my running Xamarin Forms application:

https://github.com/Crunch91/RezepteTagebuch

I'm debugging on a Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.3

I would be appreciated if someone could help.

**UPDATE:**

@idoT was right. I get an "OutOfMemoryException".

What's the best way to resize the image before it's displayed?

Comment: Can you try reducing the resolution for those images? My guess is that you get an out of memory exception

Comment: Yes, thats true. It's an out of memory exception. I tried a photo with lower resolution 400x400. Now I can display more images. But it still crashes when more than 20 images are shown.

Comment: You might need to reduce them even further, the recycle mechanism should start recycle when the image is not displayed in the page. How many images are fit into one page and how much available memory do you have in this point?

Comment: There is no restriction on the number of items. The user can add items as much as he want to. Where can I see (where do I get the Information) how much available memory do I have at this point? If you mean RAM - the smartphone is showing me 831 MB RAM total.

Comment: I will check the RAM status in case of an out of memory exception.

Answer (score 2):

There is a great article on Android Developers how to [load large bitmaps efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html):

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
    int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

Ideally you would release the memory for every picture that is not shown on screen to free up resources.

Comment: i guess this could be used for an android only project. But my trouble aims to the xamarin forms project.